# Repeat previous value of the column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops

I want to know if is possible to repeat the value of the current row until I found another one and then repeat that

WHEN DATE=201903 always is going to be the value of CODE and I want to repeat that value until I found a different value an repeat that.

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
(
     [id] VARCHAR(13), 
     [code] VARCHAR(57),
     [date] VARCHAR(13),
     [code2] VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO ForgeRock ([id], [code], [date], [code2])
VALUES (1, 21, 201903, 0),
       (1, 21, 201902, 0),
       (1, 21, 201901, 0),
       (1, 21, 201812, 0),
       (1, 21, 201811, 0),
       (1, 21, 201810, 22),
       (1, 21, 201809, 0),
       (1, 21, 201808, 0),
       (1, 21, 201807, 0);

SELECT
    *,  
    result = (CASE WHEN date = 201903 THEN code
                   WHEN date <> 201903 AND code2 = 0 THEN code
                   ELSE code2 
              END)   
FROM
    ForgeRock
```

[image: this is the result]

but the number 22 just repeat once and I want that from the moment 22 appears use that number always something like this

[image: this is what I want]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  The ideal way would be to use `LAG()` with `IGNORE NULL`s, but SQL Server does not support that.  So here is another method:

```
select fr.*,
       (case when grp = 0 then code else max(code2) over (partition by grp) end) as result
from (select fr.*,
             sum(case when code2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date desc) as grp
      from ForgeRock fr
     ) fr
order by date desc;
```

This assigns a "group" to rows for each `code2` value.  Every new `code2` generates a new group.  Then, we can use `max()` over this group to spread the value over all the rows in the group.

Finally, the outer query chooses between `code` and `code2`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5abc55d2440e7e6aba377413242f16cf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you! you are great, can you explain me whats purpose of the "SUM" you use there

Comment: @MarcosMSorianoA . . . That is to assign the "group" based on when `code2` has valid data.